# update table with the sum of column value by each id in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A like this:

```
id     amount
1      2
1      3
2      0
1      4
2      1
```

How could I update it like this :
(calculate the sum of amount by id and delete duplicate rows)

```
id  amount
1   9
2   1
```

I tried:

```
update a
set amount=sum(amount)
from a group by id;
```

and got syntax error, still working on it...

The actual table I use is:

```
row_id | subject_id | hostay
----------------------------
```

I need to update hostay with sum(hostay) and delete duplicated rows by its subject_id.

The command I tried:

```
WITH cte AS (DELETE FROM ht returning *)
INSERT INTO ht (row_id,subject_id,hostay)
SELECT row_id,subject_id,SUM(hostay)
FROM cte 
GROUP BY row_id,subject_id;
```

and the duplicated rows still exist.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you actually want to change the records in your table. Easiest way is to delete and reinsert:

```
WITH cte AS (DELETE FROM your_table RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO your_table (id, amount)
SELECT id, SUM(amount)
FROM cte 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: @Det2sial The issue is the `subject_id` column. You're grouping by id and subject_id, so if there is more than 1 distinct subject_id per id, you will end up with "duplicate" ids. So, you want distinct ids, and you want the sum of amount, but what do you want from subject_id?

Comment: Because I got error info: column "subject_id" must appear in the "group by" clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: Yep, so the thing is, what do you want from the subject_id field? Do you care about its data? Do you want to just use any of the subject_id values per id, even if that means you lose some? For example, id/subject_id of (1,3), (1,4), if you group by id so that there's only one record with an id of 1, then what do you want for the subject_id value for that single record? 3? 4? Both? Something else?

Comment: Right. I know what you mean, the thing is I need to use id and subject_id. Does that mean I have to add another delete statement? Or we can do this in one statement? I apply your answer because it illuminated me, thanks

Comment: It can be done in one statement. But as I said, it depends what value you want to use for the subject_id. As an example, let's say you just want to use the highest subject_id per id. So just take my query above, and change the SELECT bit to: `SELECT id, MAX(subject_id), SUM(amount)` - that will result in only one subject_id per id, meaning you can keep grouping by only `id`, so you won't get any duplicate ids. But whether you want the MAX or some other value is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it by following codes:

```
with B as( select sum(hostay) as hostay ,subject_id from ht  group by row_id,subject_id )

UPDATE ht  SET hostay=B.hostay  FROM B  where ht.subject_id=B.subject_id;


DELETE FROM
    ht a2
        USING ht b2 WHERE
    a2.row_id < b2.row_id
    AND a2.subject_id = b2.subject_id;
```

Ugly but it works :(

Answer (score 0):

> select id,sum(amount) as amount from table  group by id

Comment: UPDATE A SET A.amount=B.Amount FROM A INNER JOIN (select id,sum(amount) as amount from A group by id)B ON A.id=B.id